# koala facebook apprequests sent by put_connections is not seen on notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, notifications, apprequests, koala

When I use put_connections to send an apprequest by using Koala API, it is send to the related user and the request number for the application is increased by 1. But I can't see it in the main notifications section at the user facebook page. Is there a parameter to set for this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Facebook API Documentation:

> "App to User Requests do not create notifications, though they do appear in the App and Games Dashboard and increment an app bookmark counter, similar to User to User Requests."

If you want to create Requests with Notifications you have to use a User to User Request.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#app_to_user